# How save data after press back

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

How do I save the information after pressing the button Back on NavigationController?
Then use the data in the current ViewController.

Comment: What have you thought about / researched / tried?

Comment: I create @property(nonatomic) NSString str;(and synthesize) in 1st ViewController and in 2nd ViewController #import "FirstViewController",and in 2ndViewController str = textfield.txt;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

in the current controller viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationController.delegate = self;
```

then implement

```
– navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
– navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:
```

source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html